# How can I copy one collection from MongoDB using pymongo and paste to another empty collection?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

1. I want to copy full collection (e.g. name 'home').
2. Then do some changes in the 'home' collection or remove doc inside it (not a collection).
3. And then replace changed 'home' collection to its default state from item 1.

I do next:

```
db = client["database"]
home = db['home'].find()  # get collection.
db['home'].remove({})  # remove doc from home
for i in home:
      self.db['home'].insert(i)
```

But the collection is empty.

Comment: mongodb has a feature called `copyTo`, you can leverage it. refer [https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.copyTo/](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.copyTo/)

Comment: But if I delete docs from 'home' and then copyTo it, it will be empty.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem with your code example is that `find()` returns a [database cursor](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/iterate-a-cursor/) to the collection, not all documents in the collection. So when you `remove` all documents from the `home` collection, the cursor will also point to an empty collection.

In order to copy a collection to another collection in the same server, you can utilise [MongoDB Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) operator [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) and [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/out/)

```
pipeline = [ {"$match": {}}, 
             {"$out": "destination_collection"},
]
db.source_collection.aggregate(pipeline)
```

Using your example code, **now** you can do

```
source = db["source_collection"]
destination = db["destination_collection"]

# Remove all documents, or make modifications. 
source.remove({}) 

# Restore documents from the source collection.  
for doc in destination: 
      source.insert(doc)
# or instead you can just use the same aggregation method above but reverse the collection name.
```

*Note* : [db.collection.copyTo()](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.copyTo/) has been deprecated since MongoDB v3.0.

If you would like to copy to another MongoDB server, you can utilise [db.cloneCollection()](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.cloneCollection/). In PyMongo it would be a command such below:

```
db.command("cloneCollection", **{'collection': "databaseName.source_collection", 'from': "another_host:another_port"})
```

Depending on your overall goal, you may find [MongoDB BackUp methods](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/backups/) useful.

Comment: I think it should be the other way around. for doc in source: 
      destination.insert(doc)

Comment: The question on step 3 is to restore it back to it's original source collection, _after_ the source was dropped. If you're just moving from a source to destination, you can just use `$out` aggregation pipeline and stop on that stage.

Answer (score 8):

This could be the easiest way to do that, I personally prefer it, so you can add as many filters as you like:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

def CopyFromColl1ToColl2(database1,collection1,database2,collection2):
    db1 = MongoClient('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017')[database1][collection1]
    db2 = MongoClient('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017')[database2][collection2]
    #here you can put the filters you like.
    for a in db1.find():
        try:
            db2.insert(a)
            print(a)
        except:
            print('did not copy')

# You can choose the database name and the collection name
CopyFromColl1ToColl2('database1','collection1','database2','collection2')
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be better ways, but mongo>4.0 deprecated the copydb/copycollection commands.
What you can do as an alternative, you can for loop around collections, and for loop through docs and insert the db/collection you want.

> ```
>     db1_collections = client.db1.list_collection_names()
>
>     for collection in db1_collections:
>         collections_cursor = client.db1[collection].find()
>         clt = client.db2[collection]
>         for document in collections_cursor:
>             clt.with_options(write_concern=WriteConcern(w=0)).insert_one(document)
> ```