# Duplicate a MongoDB collection in Python using aggregation operations

Tags: mongodb, collections, duplicates, aggregate, pymongo

I am wondering why in Python with **pymongo** I cannot easily duplicate a collection by using aggregation operations such as `$out`. In MongoDB the command work just fine. Instead, in Python the result is just an empty collection. Here the command I performed.

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
db = client["my_database_name"] 
col = db['my_collection_name']

pipeline = [ { "$match": { } } , { "$out": "my_collection_duplicate" } ]
result = db.col.aggregate(pipeline)
```

Alternatively, I followed the suggestion presented in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52777343/12178795) thread and it works, although the operation is far much slower.
I am performing some recursive operations over the same collection, then I have to re-generate each time it in its 'original' form.
I hope someone can enlighten me where I am wrong.

Comment: shouldn't that be `col.aggregate` instead of `db.col.aggregate`?

Comment: You're right. My mistake. Now it works perfectly. Thank you a lot!